# Does the JVM create background threads when updating a HashMap, such that a HashSet of its keys may be 'out of date' in a single threaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, synchronization, hashset

I have a HashSet which contains the keys of a HashMap, and update the contents of the HashMap, adding a new key in the process. After I've done this, I then want to use the HashSet of keys again, since I know that they kept up to date with the keys of the HashMap. I just want to make sure that this is all done by the same thread, and that there is no concurrency going on here that I might be unaware of, such that I tell the HashMap to add the new entry, and before it has updated I have used the HashSet information while it is out of date.

**In code:**

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashSet<String> myHashSet = myHashMap.keySet();

... processing ...

myHashMap.put(new_key, value);

... use the **original** HashSet of keys, myHashSet ...
```

Could the above situation occur, given that this is the only thread created by the programmer, such that myHashMap and myHashSet would be out of sync? **I'm not talking about the programmer creating more than one thread - the main program runs in a single thread (see above).**

Comment: if you have to ask this question the **short answer** is *yes, everything can go wrong* and the **long answer** is **too broad**.

Comment: My question is different to the one that you marked as a duplicate. Did you even read it before you down marked it? I only have a single thread; I want to know if the JVM creates any in the background to deal with the updating of the HashMap.

Comment: you question is also **unclear** as well as one of many **duplicates** and **too-broad** then, because your question mentions *concurrency* and multiple threads and uses the word *multithreading*. If you have a single thread and you are asking this and don't understand that the duplicate has the answers you need, you need to try and do some more reading about what concurrency and multithreading really is and how the JVM actually works. What would make you think the JVM would do what you are worried about? All of which are even **more too broad** than the existing question.

Comment: I know full well what concurrency and multithreading are. Could you please unblock my question and then I can change it.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268468/auto-remove-thanks-in-advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they won't because the key set is a view onto the actual keys in the HashMap.

From the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet--):

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in
>   the set, and vice-versa.

And you can see the same in [OpenJDK's implementation of HashMap](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java).

So for a single-threaded program these should always be in sync.

The Java collections classes don't do things with threads internally because it would make using them too difficult and error prone.  They leave the threading model to the calling code and just provide guarantees (or otherwise) about which operations are thread-safe.